# Jquery get SubString if slash exist

Tags: jquery, performance

how can I get the last number in this string example  `5\\6\\45` in jquery .Some time my String contain only number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   var str="5\\6\\45";
    var arr = str.split("\\");
    arr[arr.length-1]
```

or

```
str.split("\\").pop();
```

[**.pop()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

> Removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

Comment: arr[arr.length] will be undefined

Comment: arr[arr.lenght-1] is needed. Also, OP had backslash :)

Comment: Just as a side note (simpler code), another option is `arr.pop()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by using `lastIndexOf` method. [Check live demo](http://jsbin.com/ixuyel/1/edit)

```
function getLastNumber(str) {
  var index = str.lastIndexOf('\\');
  if (index < 0) return str;
  var newString = str.substr(index+1);
  return newString;
}

var str = '5\\6\\45';
console.log(getLastNumber(str)); //gives 45

str = '451234';
console.log(getLastNumber(str)); //gives 451234

str = '5\\6';
console.log(getLastNumber(str)); //gives 6
```

Just out of curiosity, I checked performance of `array split solution` against `lastIndexof` solution and [Here are the results on jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/lastindex)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only "\" as separators:

```
last_number = my_string.split("\\").reverse()[0]
```

Comment: If this is being done several times and/or the array has many values, the performance impact of calling `reverse()` over and over could be significant.

Comment: Yes, I know. PSR's solution will be faster in all cases. I still like to use "reverse()" when not too costy, just because I find it easier to quickly read the code.